# Heap error in VS2010

Tags: c++, windows, msdn

I'm trying to  implement the program, which recognizes Windows file attributes. I have a code, but sometimes, I receive heap error after passing return in the main block. Thank you for your attention and help!

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <conio.h>

_TCHAR* getStringAttributes(int value, _TCHAR* str[])
{
    DWORD d = GetFileAttributes(str[value]);
    _TCHAR* temp;

    switch(d)
    {
        case 2048: temp = L"Compressed\n"; break;
        case 32: temp = L"Archive\n"; break;
        case 16: temp = L"Directory\n"; break;
        case 16384: temp = L"Encrypted\n"; break;
        case 2: temp = L"Hidden\n"; break;
        case 128: temp = L"Normal\n"; break;
        case 1: temp = L"Readonly\n"; break;
        case 4: temp = L"System\n"; break;
        case 256: temp = L"Temporary\n"; break;
        default: temp = L"Error or unsupported attribute\n"; break;
    }

    return temp;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    _TCHAR* attString = new _TCHAR();
    char* ynAnswer = new char();

    if(argv[1] == NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\n","You didn't type file path. Try again?[Y/N]");
        gets_s(ynAnswer,10);

        if(*ynAnswer == 'y' || *ynAnswer == 'Y')
        {
            printf("%s\n","Type in a path to the file");
            argv[1] = new _TCHAR();
            _getws(argv[1]);

            if(argv[1] != L"")
            {
                printf("%s","Attribute: ");
                attString = getStringAttributes(1,argv);

                _tprintf(attString);
                printf("%s","for\n");
                _tprintf(argv[1]);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%s","Attribute: ");
        attString = getStringAttributes(1,argv);
        _tprintf(attString);
    }

    printf("%s","Goodbye");
    getch();

    delete[] ynAnswer;
    delete[] attString;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You only allocate `attString` and `ynAnswer` with enough storage for one character, so you are corrupting the heap.

Comment: What should I do then?

Answer (score 1):

you input whole string into 1 or 2 bytes strings.
These allocations:

```
_TCHAR* attString = new _TCHAR();
char* ynAnswer = new char();
```

Allocate only 1 item array.

it should be:

```
_TCHAR* attString = new _TCHAR[MAX_SIZE];
char* ynAnswer = new char[MAX_SIZE];
```

When `MAX_SIZE` must beeb defuned as macro.

even better is to use:

```
 wstring attString ;
 string  ynAnswer;

 wcin>> attString;
 cin>>  ynAnswer;
```

More problem is the allocation in the line:

```
 argv[1] = new _TCHAR();
```

in addition to the previous answered problem, in this line `argv[1]` may not even exists.
You should input to other buffer.

it can be like this:

```
wstring argv1;
if(argc <2){
   wcin>>argv1;
}else{
   argv1=argv[1]; 
}
```

now use `argv1` instead of `argv[1]`

One more thing:

You are using `_TCHAR` as `WCHAR`.

when you use `_TCHAR` strings should be decalared as:

`_T("some string")`

not as:

`L"some string"`.